# Legend within a loop and subplot matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, legend, subplot

I want to create a legend within a loop of two variables. I tried different things but I don't know how to assign in the legend that there is the name for the black and the red line for each iteration within the subplot.

Basically what I would like to have is In subplot 1 the legend should read
`'Sandvik NO';'Sandvik NO 24h mean'` in subplot 2 `'Sandvik NO2';'Sandvik NO2 24h mean'` and so on for the six subplots

here is the code

```
legend3=[{'Sandvik NO';'Sandvik NO_2';'Sandvik NO_x';'Sandvik    PM_{10}';'Sandvik PM_{10-2.5}';'Sandvik PM_{2.5}'}];

figure
for i=1:6
    subplot(2,3,i)
    plot(d0(:,26),d0(:,18+i)','ko','MarkerSize',10)
    hold on
    plot(dd_day(:,26),dd_day(:,18+i)','ro','MarkerSize',6,'MarkerFaceColor','r')
    hold on
    ylabel(' ug m^{-3}','fontsize',14)
    xlabel(' time ','fontsize',14)
    datetick('x','mmm')
    legend(legend3{i})
    xlim([All_time(1) All_time(6551)])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
figure
for i=1:6

    legend3={['Sandvik NO', num2str(i)];['Sandvik NO',num2str(i) ,' 24h mean']};

    subplot(2,3,i)
    plot(d0(:,26),d0(:,18+i)','ko','MarkerSize',10)
    hold on
    plot(dd_day(:,26),dd_day(:,18+i)','ro','MarkerSize',6,'MarkerFaceColor','r')
    hold on
    ylabel(' ug m^{-3}','fontsize',14)
    xlabel(' time ','fontsize',14)
    datetick('x','mmm')
    legend(legend3)
    xlim([All_time(1) All_time(6551)])
end
```

Comment: Hi no this does not work, this will put each string in a different subplot, BUt the two strings should be as a legend in a one suplot

Comment: Then try combine it with Theodor's answer and try `h = plot(d0(:,26),d0(:...` and then later `legend(h, legend3)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
figure
p1 = subplot(1,2,1)
plot(sin(1:100),'r')
p2 = subplot(1,2,2) 
plot(cos(1:100),'b')
legend(p1,'test')
legend(p2,'test2')
```

and adapt it to your needs. It should work!